# Assembly - Structure

Tags: assembly, x86

---

```
Employee STRUCT

    IdNum BYTE "000000000" ; 9 
    LastName BYTE 30 DUP(0) ; 30
    ALIGN WORD ; 1 byte added
    Years WORD 30 ; 2
    ALIGN DWORD ; 2 byte added
    SalaryHistory DWORD 0,0,0,0 ; 16
Employee ENDS


employees Employee 5 DUP (<"123456789","AAAAAAAA",30h,4 DUP(0EEEEEEEEh)>)
```

---

When I use

```
mov eax,TYPE Employee ; it says used 60byte space
```

but when I saw on the memory it says use 57 bytes space

```
mov esi,SIZEOF Employee;
mov eax,employees[esi].Years
```

so if I use that statement I never get the right value.
but if I move 057h to esi, I could get the right value that is 30h, why?

[image]

but lets try some code...

mov esi,TYPE employee ; which is says 60 dec

mov ax, employees[esi].Years ; this would be never get the right value

---

**if I didnot use align, it would be correct**

---

mov esi,TYPE Employee ; which is 57 dec mov ax,employees[esi].Years ; would get the right value FF

mov esi,0 mov eax,0 mov ax, employees[esi].Years ; AX = 0xFF

yes its absolutely the right value, because from the base pointer...Try to compile mov esi,TYPE employee

With align it would be cannot get the proper value, without align on struct i could get the proper value... I tried it almost 1 day to get this information

Could someone told me the right reason?

Comment: I can't fully understand your question. Anyway, have you considered padding?

Comment: There are few discrepancies in your question, which make it difficult to follow without actually using own MASM (which I don't have).  If those `ALIGN` inside `STRUCT` works, then the offsets should be IdNum=`0`, LastName=`9`, Years=`40` (39+1), SalaryHistory=`44` (42+2), ENDS=`60` (BTW notice the second align is doing +2 only, not +3, because `WORD` is 2B). But then I don't get how you end with memory view where the Years `0x30` is at offset `39`, that's like the `ALIGN` didn't work at all, or your filling by `DUP` is wrong. And that memory view with `qwords` is confusing, bytes view pls?

Comment: Looking once more at that memory view, your screen must be created by different source code than in the question. It would make some sense if `Years BYTE`, then the `Years` without alignment can be at offset 39, and `SalaryHistory` can be then 40, and 40+16 = 56. [MCVE] would probably help (for somebody who has MASM and VS, not for me).

Comment: `Years WORD 30 ; 1` - I don't think so :-) Last I checked, a word was *two* bytes.

Comment: sorry, i forget to edit, because I edit on my MASM
and didnot re write it again
thank you

Comment: I did google for 2 minutes, and it looks the Microsoft itself does use manual padding in their *.inc files, i.e. instead of first align you can use `__1_align_to_2 BYTE   ; +1 byte alignment to current size 40`. Even `Employee STRUCT 4` supposed to align every field to `DWORD` may crash in new versions of MASM, works only in older ones. (welcome to the world of MS :) ... I personally prefer OSS world, where I may eventually fix bugs myself, if I get annoyed enough).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered by the author, Kip Irvine:

> It looks like we should avoid using `ALIGN` inside structure definitions.

[image: Answer pict]

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test on this also, with just a small change by filling in all 30 characters of the LastName field. The SIZEOF value moved to EDX is indeed 0x3C (60 decimal), which takes into account the ALIGN statements in the structure definition. But when you examine the initialized structure in the Debug Memory window, each instance of the employees array takes only 0x39 bytes (57 decimal). Here is my source code, showing the hex offsets of the fields:

Bottom line: the ALIGN directives seem to have no effect on the alignment of data when you declare an instance of the structure with field initializers.

```
Employee STRUCT                            
 IdNum BYTE "000000000"                
 LastName BYTE 30 DUP(0)               
 ALIGN WORD                           
 Years WORD 30                         
 ALIGN DWORD                          
 SalaryHistory DWORD 0, 0, 0, 0        
Employee ENDS

.data
employees Employee 5 DUP(<"111111111", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", 0FFh, 4 DUP(0EEEEEEEEh)>)
; hex offsets:  00--08, 09-26, 27-28, 29-38.


.code
main proc
mov eax,offset employees
mov edx,SIZEOF Employee    ; 0x3C
```

The good news is, the following statements correctly load the value of "Years" into the AX register:

```
mov esi,0
mov eax,0
mov ax, employees[esi].Years         ; AX = 0xFF
```

Comment: Hello sir, im very happy you comment on my post

but lets try on your code...
mov esi,TYPE employee ; which is 60 dec, its says index number 1 on your book

mov ax, employees[esi].Years ; this would be never get the right value

if I didnot use align, it would be correct


----
mov esi,TYPE Employee ; which is 57 dec
mov ax,employees[esi].Years ; would get the right value FF